# Limits of f(x) and proposition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $ f: \; ]0, +\infty[\; \to \Bbb{R} $ be a derivative function so that  $ f'(x) ≠ 0 $ for all $ x > 0 $ and $ \lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty} f(x)= + \infty $
>
> Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty } x^{2}e^{-f(x))}$ is: a) $ 0 $, b) Needs more information about $f(x)$.

I used L'hopital and got $ \frac{2x}{e^{f(x)} f'(x)} $ and then again $ \frac{2}{e^{f(x)} f''(x)+ e^{f(x)}[f'(x)]^{2}} $.

But I got stuck there, don't know if I can say anything about $f''(x)$. I tried a lot of functions and everyone of them goes to $0$... but that does not say anything.

Comment: There's actually a fairly simple counterexample, I'd say you should go back to the original statement and try some more functions

Comment: I'm not sure how you're even applying L'Hopital here to be honest

Comment: @Anon He rewrote as $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^{f(x)}},$ and the limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}.$ It's a pretty reasonable approach imo, but it doesn't really work. (the second application is not justified as we're only given that the function is differentiable once)

Comment: Ahh yes... f(x) = ln (x).. I tried before but I made a mistake.. now I got ∞.. then needs more information

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind, but if the first bracket is a square bracket as it's written then there is actually a bit more that you have to do to fix it up. But you're definitely on the right track now (edit: it may be that both are open since the $\infty$ is also given a square bracket. if it's an open bracket then you're good to go)